# Backend JS errors when enabling SSL

Tags: ssl, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.4 and CloudFlare free SSL.

Three issues appeared in the Backend after activating SSL:

1. When editing a product, I cannot save because the save buttons are deactivated and show a spinner icon. When SSL is turned OFF, the save buttons appear after a few seconds as expected. the WYSIWYG buttons are also missing.

   The console says:

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: tb_pathToImage is not defined [in jquery.thickbox.js]
2. When editing a CMS page, the page content input field is hidden. The label "page content" is visible but the source shows that the input has a inline style `visibility:hidden`. the WYSIWYG buttons are missing too.
3. The dashboard does not load any data. All tables are shown but no live data gets loaded. There are loads of spinners rotating indefinitely.

   The console says:

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: dashboard_ajax_url is not defined [in dashboard.js]

All issues only exist when using https. Do you know what is causing those issues?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry but the last version of Prestashop is 1.6.1.4 did you meant that ?

Comment: Sorry I meant 1.6.1.4 indeed

Comment: Did you try deleting every folders under `/cache/`? just let `cache/index.php` in place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Florian. I did this but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was one of the speed features from Cloudflare which was causing all of my JS errors.

"Rocket loader" feature which is meant to improve load time for pages that include JavaScript can break JS code, especially when JQUERY is used.

I hope this helps someone as I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Thanks